# How to prevent scroll up doing nothing when the value is too big?

Tags: scrolling

When calling `(scroll-up N)` with a large value that would exceed the buffer length - nothing happens.

For example:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f4>") (lambda () (interactive) (scroll-up 10000)))
```

Prints `End of buffer` but doesn't scroll.

Is there a way to scroll that clamps to buffer bounds instead of failing silently?

Comment: oops, should have been scroll up.

Comment: In my test evaluating `(scroll-up LARGE-NUMBER)`, I see an `"End of buffer"` in the echo area and `*Messages*` buffer -- this is a quit/error message ...  An example of how to get Emacs to fail silently without the quit/error message may be helpful to other forum participants.

Comment: Right, this is what I see too, no scrolling in this case. - Updated question.

Comment: Perhaps using a `condition-case` to "[r]egain control when an error is signaled" might be helpful ....

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>PageDown</kbd> runs `scroll-up-command` which already does something similar if [`scroll-error-top-bottom`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Scrolling.html#index-scroll_002derror_002dtop_002dbottom-587) is non-nil (it's nil by default). It works by calling `scroll-up` and catching the error. So either call `scroll-up-command` with `scroll-error-top-bottom` set to non-nil or do the same error catching.

```el
(defun scroll-up-lots ()
  (interactive "^P")
  (condition-case nil
      (scroll-up 10000)
    (end-of-buffer
      (forward-line 10000))))
(put 'scroll-up-lots 'scroll-command t)
```

The `scroll-command` property makes the command behave with [`scroll-preserve-screen-position`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Scrolling.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bscroll_002dcommand_007d-property-589).

Answer (score 0):

Adding my own answer thanks to @Gilles's since it adjusts scroll instead moving the cursor with forward lines.

```lisp
(defun scroll-by-lines (lines)
  (if (< lines 0)
    (condition-case nil
      (scroll-down (- lines))
      (beginning-of-buffer nil))
    (condition-case nil
      (scroll-up lines)
      (end-of-buffer
        (let ((lines (- (count-lines (window-start) (point-max)) 1)))
          (when (> lines 0) (scroll-up lines)))))))
```